# How to plot list of segments?

Tags: plotting, geometry

Consider the following table:

```
tab={{-0.6041040222514815, -0.10723923864910397, -24.476345728249754, \
-0.5933325958251954, -0.10744277954101562, -24.78504638671875}, 
   {-0.6018866179845486, -0.10816925132674751, -24.392578407802162, \
-0.5931969451904296, -0.10744576454162598, -24.7948779296875}, 
   {-0.5935374592447612, -0.10841003269258406, -24.28559170136151, \
-0.5932831954956055, -0.10744386672973633, -24.78862548828125}, 
   {-0.5973404981998902, -0.11170446279047075, -24.319644205817813, \
-0.5933410263061524, -0.10744258880615234, -24.78443603515625}, 
   {-0.5943405693392554, -0.10947296158562043, -24.291988301929965, \
-0.5931867218017578, -0.10744599342346192, -24.79561767578125}, 
   {-0.6650848128533421, -0.06620504550320766, -24.31987511065071, \
-0.6660238647460938, -0.06281246185302734, -24.78384765625}, \
{-0.6818788149744563, -0.06004261791553454, -23.598436426900427, \
-0.6659500885009766, 
     -0.06280965328216553, -24.78990966796875}, {-0.6668736038491707, \
-0.06259470335623302, -24.44772130046938, -0.6659196472167969, \
-0.06280849456787109, -24.79240966796875}, 
   {-0.6711532983322678, -0.06320520388916682, -24.46243352941391, \
-0.6660601043701172, -0.06281383991241456, -24.78087158203125}, 
   {-0.6779088358540455, -0.0673112224402137, -23.184988776330016, \
-0.6658786773681641, -0.06280694007873536, -24.79577392578125}, 
   {-0.6767018750107373, -0.06553659081403938, -23.419199771128543, \
-0.665989990234375, -0.0628111743927002, -24.78662841796875}, 
   {-0.6757463066565861, -0.06313673484258156, -24.339537235682364, \
-0.6659801483154297, -0.06281079769134522, -24.78744140625}, \
{0.6196361845023636, -0.1699447892343164, -23.959601356023377, 
  0.6063905715942383, 
     -0.16637937545776368, -24.7818603515625}, {0.5820992053960766, \
-0.08055016977769679, -24.317969970145384, 
  0.5806598663330078, -0.07968908309936523, -24.7961279296875}, 
   {0.663120395435219, 0.3365388838252501, -24.337648981495903, 
  0.6557691955566406, 
  0.3325455856323242, -24.78313720703125}, {0.6629512249484795, 
  0.3381368621552924, -24.314963358189818, 0.6557929992675782, 
     0.33255352020263673, -24.781376953125}, {0.4977389139309393, \
-0.3860099715564398, -24.3576201169801, 
  0.5065310668945313, -0.3824906921386719, -24.78898681640625}, 
   {0.5979628472593581, -0.10355711932936178, -24.47573690525918, 
  0.5918756866455078, -0.10321792602539062, -24.794873046875}, \
{0.6531602658221168, -0.11157431824864596, -19.149249920631068, 
  0.5920129013061524, 
     -0.10326374053955079, -24.785227050781252}, {0.5996281785651482, \
-0.10414278787468609, -24.286861400104858, 
  0.5918636322021484, -0.10321389198303223, -24.79572265625}, 
   {0.6080975356723294, -0.10711793197877095, -23.8989338370412, 
  0.5919087219238282, -0.10322895050048829, -24.792551269531252}, \
{0.5977686902713429, -0.10222033883700773, -24.27346323150313, 
  0.5920152282714843, 
     -0.1032645320892334, -24.78506103515625}};
```

It has the form `(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)`, i.e. represents sets of two points. Is it possible to make a plot with segments joining the two points for all the table rows?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand how the plot should be structured, but does `Graphics3D[ Line[{{#1, #2, #3}, {#4, #5, #6}}]& @@@ tab]` do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics3D@(Line /@ (Partition[#, 3] & /@ tab))
```

which is (with fewer mandatory parentheses) equivalent to:

```
Graphics3D@Map[Line, Partition[#, 3] & /@ tab, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
Graphics3D[Line[TakeDrop[#, 3]] & /@ tab]
```